# Django: how to inject data when overriding get_queryset()?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Very begginer with the Django class based view.
I had a ListView that worked well but displayed all the objects. I wanted to filter this, and here what I did, following some examples found:

**models.py**:

```
class FolderElement(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class FolderMedia(TimeStampedModel):
    folder_element = models.ForeignKey(FolderElement)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filepath_folder)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

**views.py**:

```
class FolderMediaListView(ListView):
    model = FolderMedia
    template_name = "book.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.folder_element = get_object_or_404(FolderElement,
                                                pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return FolderMedia.filter(folder_element=self.folder_element)

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        files = [ serialize(p) for p in self.get_queryset() ]
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response
```

But now that I overrided the `get_queryset()` method, I don't understand how I'm supposed to inject the `pk`parameter to the view sothat the filter works. Currently, using pdb, I can see that `self.kwargs` equals `{}` into the get_queryset() method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword arguments (`kwargs`) that the Django URL dispatcher passes to the view comes from the following:

- Captured parameters in the URL expression
- Additional arguments specified in the URL definition

All of them in urls.py.

So, for example, in order to get an ID form the URL in a form: `/folder/id/`:

```
url(r'folder/(?P<pk>\d+)/', FolderMediaListView.as_view)
```

Or if the id is constant (more rarely), you can pass it as an additional argument:

```
url(r'folder/', FolderMediaListView.as_view, {'pk': 1})
```

More information on the subject in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply it in the URL. For example:

```
url(r'folder/(?P<id>\d+)/media', FolderMediaListView.as_view, name='folder_media_list')
```